# OSX 10.8, Xcode 4.4 Make and gcc gone from environment

Tags: xcode, gcc, makefile, osx-mountain-lion

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion OSX 10.8 and along with that I foolishly upgraded to Xcode 4.4.

However, after this upgrade "make" is gone and things like gcc -v also do not work.

This is a big thing since I am writing my phD and I rely on make to compile my LaTeX docs...

Downloading the "command line tools"

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.4_gm_seed/cltools10_8gmseed6938077a.dmg

Is apparently not allowed for non-paying dev accounts.

What kind of foolishness is this?

Comment: That was an error on Apple's part; they seem to have this issue with every Xcode update. The command-line tools do not require a paying developer account. Try installing them from Xcode > Preferences > Downloads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're not gone, they've just been relocated to inside Xcode's app bundle.  This is actually nicer as it allows side by side installs of different XCode/SDK versions.

You can find them at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin

Also check out the xcode-select tool to allow you to choose the current active toolchain path.

Comment: I figured that out already but thanks for the constructive comment. Now I need to add these to the path again...

Comment: I put in a quick `sudo ln -s  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer /Developer` to keep my old path (`/Developer/usr/bin`) working

Comment: Thanks Andrew... your suggestion, along with that of Mark contributed to the solution: /Developer had moved to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

I ran a quick /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make usr/bin/make (usr/bin was on my path already so that was convenient) and things are running smoothly again!

Comment: You can also run "xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" to set the location of the Developer folder, then "xcrun make". (You can replace "make" with "gcc" or whatever you like.)

Answer (score 3):

I did the same thing as you this morning. To fix it, I just added the following to my ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
```

Comment: Yup, that should also do it... I have to admit though that my Vim skills were not good enough to get that line edited in :). I might use LaTeX but I'm not much of a command line wizard :)

I also noticed that X11 is no longer included in Mountain Lion... this upgrade was a pain...

Comment: just put it in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile. as for xll, check out XQuartz

Comment: Yup, XQuarts is available from xquartz.macosforge.org and is apparently needed for ghostscript to work...

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly,

The "Downloads" interface inside Xcode 4.4 seems to point to the following location for downloading the "Command line tools":

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.4_gm_seed/cltools10_8gmseed6938077a.dmg

Judging by the "gm" reference in that URL I think this is an error. Without a paying dev account you cannot download this...

Comment: Even with a paying account it doesn't work. The command line tools are also not on the website. Contacted Apple and they seem to admit it is most likely a mistake on their part...

Answer (score 0):

I issued the export PATH command, and then tried to compile hello.c, but compilation fails because it does not find the file stdio.h. So, I changed the include statement to specify the full path  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h, but then compilation fails because it does not find 3 other .h files.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 printf("Hello World \n");
}
gcc hello.c -o hello
hello.c:1:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
hello.c: In function ‘main’:
hello.c:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
gcc hello.c -o hello
In file included from hello.c:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:23: error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:65:26: error: Availability.h: No such file or directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:67:20: error: _types.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I was just looking for this myself in Xcode 4.6:

1. Install Xcode
2. Go to Preferences->Downloads->Components and there will be an "Install" button next to "Command Line Tools"